# No build system while trying to use jshint in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint

I am trying to use jshint for JavaScript programming on Sublime Text 3(Linux Mint). I have installed jshint through node and I am able to access the jshint command using the terminal.
Afterwards I have installed the SublimeLinter-jshint package in Sublime Text.
However, when I am trying to use the build feature, I am getting a report that there is no build system. I have seen the options for build systems in the menu and there is no option for jshint.
All the websites I have seen show that jshint will be automatically activated. Am I missing any step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sublimelinter-jshint is a plugin for the sublimelinter package. It only provides a interface to the jshint. You still need the sublimelinter. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter

It can run in several modes to lint in background, on save, or when explicitly stated. I don't think it uses the sublime text build system.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused there for a moment.